# Alternative app to GoodNotes for Windows 10

Tags: windows, note-taking, annotation

I recently bought a Windows 2-in-1 device with a pen. My main goal is taking research notes.

OneNote is a really good app obivously, but it lacks some features that I used to have in iPad with GoodNotes.

In summary, I'd like to be able to

- import .pdf documents page by page,
- resize the pages so that I can take notes next to slides instead of being limited by blank spaces,
- insert blank pages of same size,
- disable hand-drawing (enable only-pen drawing).

The 2-in-1 I have is Asus Transformer Pro, and I use it in both tablet mode and desktop mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [PDF Annotator](https://www.pdfannotator.com/en/how)? Seems like it could be a fit:

- import your .pdfs,
- add/remove margin to fit your annotations and comments,
- insert blank pages,
- (not sure about hand-writing disabling, but it looks like it works just with stylus),
- a whole bunch of other features, more or less interesting or useful.

It might not be a perfect fit, but could still be worth a look if you don't find anything at all.